# Run a Cloud Function or Cloud Run after a Cloud Scheduler job

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

Is it possible to run a Function/Cloud Run after a Cloud Scheduler job?

For example, I want to store in Firestore if a job was successful or had any error, in order to do this, I was wondering if I could "connect" the events from Cloud Scheduler to a Cloud Function or Cloud Run.

Is it possible?

These events (image bellow)

[image]

EDIT: Maybe using Eventarc?

Comment: Did you have a look to Eventarc?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, now I am using Eventarc